# how to set Cython language_level in magic

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cython

I have a conda env using python 2.7. Cython was installed along with it with the version 0.29.6.

I tried to use Cython magic on Jupyter:

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as np
```

which returns a warning `Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release!`

The warning looks clear. But I don't know where I can set the language_level.

Do I need to go into the site-package and manually change anything?

Thanks

J

Comment: Did you try `%%cython?` for displaying help of %%cython-magic?

Comment: @ead thanks, just found out that I can %%cython -2 or -3 to set language_level

Answer (score 1):

Just find out I can use -2 or -3 to define the version

```
%%cython -2
```